# How to change output pattern in shell?

Tags: postgresql, shell, psql

I run the psql command from a Linux shell. The resulting output looks like a table:

```
  Name         Age
  -----------------
  John          24
```

But I would like to get the result with commas like this:

```
   Name,Age
   John,24
```

How do I change the output format from the shell? I'm using Centos 5.5 and postgresql 8.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
=> \a
Output format is unaligned.
=> \f ,
Field separator is ",".

=> select 'John' "Name", 24 "Age";
Name,Age
John,24
```